# Extract value from XML not working with querying nodes or value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm working in SQL Server 2016, and I'm trying to extract the `<Org>Insurance Technologies Corporation</Org>` value from the XML below.

I've tried querying the value using `nodes` and `value` in my tsql code, but to no avail as I keep getting a `NULL` value for the Rater column.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in either case.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my XML:

```
<ACORD xmlns="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1.11.0/xml/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SignonRq>
    <SignonTransport>
      <SignonRoleCd>Agent</SignonRoleCd>
      <CustId>
        <SPName>turborater.com</SPName>
        <CustLoginId>99999</CustLoginId>
      </CustId>
    </SignonTransport>
    <ClientDt>2019-07-05T11:05:36</ClientDt>
    <CustLangPref>EN-US</CustLangPref>
    <ClientApp>
      <Org>Insurance Technologies Corporation</Org>
      <Name>ITC.Insurance.EmpowerAnnSvngsRR.TX</Name>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    </ClientApp>
  </SignonRq>
 </ACORD>
```

Here is my tsql code using nodes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT rtr.BridgedDate, rtr.RealTimeRequestSysId, rtr.QuoteId, rtr.AgentId, rtr.XmlRequest
        , x.m.value('(Org)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Rater
    FROM dbo.AUT_RealTimeRequest rtr
        OUTER APPLY rtr.XmlRequest.nodes('ACORD/SignonRq/ClientApp') x(m)
    WHERE rtr.BridgedDate BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2020-11-30 23:59:59.997'
) y
WHERE y.AgentId = 3
AND y.QuoteId IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY y.QuoteId asc, y.BridgedDate asc;
```

Here is my tsql code using value:

```
SELECT rtr.BridgedDate, rtr.XMLRequest, 
rtr.XMLRequest.value('(/ACORD/SignonRq/ClientApp/Org)[1]','varchar(max)') as RaterValue
FROM dbo.AUT_RealTimeRequest rtr
WHERE rtr.QuoteId IS NOT NULL
AND rtr.AgentId = 3 --21001
AND rtr.BridgedDate BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2020-11-30 23:59:59.997'
ORDER BY rtr.QuoteId asc, rtr.BridgedDate asc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're **ignoring** the XML namespace present in your XML data:

```
<ACORD xmlns="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1.11.0/xml/" 
       *****************************************************************
       This is the "default" XML namespace for this XML data
```

Try this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1.11.0/xml/')
    SELECT 
        rtr.BridgedDate, rtr.XMLRequest, 
        rtr.XMLRequest.value('(/ACORD/SignonRq/ClientApp/Org)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS RaterValue
    FROM 
        dbo.AUT_RealTimeRequest rtr
    WHERE 
        rtr.QuoteId IS NOT NULL
        AND rtr.AgentId = 3 --21001
        AND rtr.BridgedDate BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2020-11-30 23:59:59.997'
    ORDER BY 
        rtr.QuoteId ASC, rtr.BridgedDate ASC;
```

Comment: thanks for your help and time in replying.  That worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to handle the namespace:

```
declare @xml xml='<ACORD xmlns="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1.11.0/xml/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SignonRq>
    <SignonTransport>
      <SignonRoleCd>Agent</SignonRoleCd>
      <CustId>
        <SPName>turborater.com</SPName>
        <CustLoginId>99999</CustLoginId>
      </CustId>
    </SignonTransport>
    <ClientDt>2019-07-05T11:05:36</ClientDt>
    <CustLangPref>EN-US</CustLangPref>
    <ClientApp>
      <Org>Insurance Technologies Corporation</Org>
      <Name>ITC.Insurance.EmpowerAnnSvngsRR.TX</Name>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    </ClientApp>
  </SignonRq>
 </ACORD>'

; WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1.11.0/xml/') 
SELECT 
     l.value (
    'Org[1]'
    ,'varchar(100)' ) Org
    FROM @xml.nodes('//SignonRq') r(n) CROSS APPLY r.n.nodes('ClientApp') lines(l)
```

results:

[image]